# Why is checking equality of open generic types inconsistent?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

For some reason this:

```cs
typeof(Dictionary<string,string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                                 .GetInterfaces()
                                 .Contains(typeof(IDictionary<,>))
```

is `false` but this:

```cs
typeof(Dictionary<string,string>).GetInterfaces()
                                 .Any(i => i.IsGenericType
                                        && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
```

is `true`, even though they both appear as `IDictionary'2` in the debugger with the same GUID.

In the first example, `[0]` in the interface array is `IDictionary'2`, and if I compare it directly with `typeof` (without `.Contains(...)`) with either `==` or `.Equals(...)` and even `.IsAssignableFrom(...)` it's the same outcome.

Please, someone tell me why!

Comment: See [Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition).

Comment: I'm not using it on an open type.

Comment: The linked question is about interfaces, but the point of classes is the same.

Comment: I don't understand, I didn't vote to close for the mentioned duplicate but another one that I don't remember, it seems to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the interfaces returned from `.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces()` aren't "generic type definitions" (their `IsGenericTypeDefinition` is `false`), so they can't be strictly equal to `IDictionary<,>` (that is a generic type definition, with `IsGenericTypeDefinition` that is `true`).

The second block of code drills from the interfaces to their generic type definition and lets you make the comparison.

A simple example about what happens:

```
class MyDictionary<TKey2, TValue2> : IDictionary<TKey2, TValue2>
{
    public TValue2 this[TKey2 key] { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public ICollection<TKey2> Keys => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public ICollection<TValue2> Values => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public int Count => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public bool IsReadOnly => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void Add(TKey2 key, TValue2 value) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey2, TValue2> item) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void Clear() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey2, TValue2> item) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public bool ContainsKey(TKey2 key) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey2, TValue2>[] array, int arrayIndex) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey2, TValue2>> GetEnumerator() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public bool Remove(TKey2 key) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey2, TValue2> item) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public bool TryGetValue(TKey2 key, out TValue2 value) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

then:

```
var interfaces = typeof(MyDictionary<string, string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces();
var idict1 = interfaces[0];
var idict2 = idict1.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

Console.WriteLine(idict1);
Console.WriteLine(idict2);
```

Result:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey2,TValue2] <-- This is what you get with GetInterfaces()
System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue]   <-- And this is the generic type definition
```

It is quite clear that the `idict1` can't be a `IDictionary<,>`, because it is a `IDictionary<TKey2, TValue2>`

Comment: I see now, that for some reason the type arguments are `TKey` and `TValue` not actual types, so it's like a pseudo-constructed type. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Actually those are the type arguments for both. I wonder why one says it's open and the other doesn't?

Comment: @Nintynuts They only have the same name... I'll prepare an example

Comment: @Nintynuts See https://dotnetfiddle.net/ym2kUq